# Android Hardware acceleration for Views with LAYER_TYPE_NONE

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, opengl-es, hardware-acceleration

I was not able to find a clear answer (found some contradicting answers) for the following scenario:

1. Turn on  Android HW accelerations
   (by adding  to the manifest `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`)
2. Set a View to layer type LAYER_TYPE_NONE [`view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE,null)`].

Does the view is rendered on the GPU or skia (software)?

I think that it will use Hardware rendering model but just not backed by Hardware layer (the view will rendered into screen without any "BITMAP/TEXTURE" like buffer on the GPU, but still should be rendered by the GPU and not skia).

Am I correct?
And if I am, Why google called the disable HW Acceleration for View with the same API while just setting the layer type to software, where it is not related to layers at all, they should had different function for disabling the view HW acceleration and setting the view layer to software should have done the same as  `Canvas.saveLayer()`.

References say that:

> LAYER_TYPE_NONE: the View is rendered normally, and is not backed by
>   an off-screen buffer.

by normally they mean software/hardware according to the manifest file?

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html

Comment: Why the down vote? label? down vote is for bad questions not in-accurate lables...

Comment: Have you found an answer to your questions?  I am curious as well.

Comment: Still look for a complete answer, would love for some help, I tend to believe that hardware layer means rendering to texture buffer before rendering to screen, which forces hardware accelerations in case the app is using software rendering, and in case the app is already using HW acceleration, this will just add the stage of rendering to buffer before rendering to screen, which allows better animations performance.